# Patterned Vector in base

Tags: r

I'd like to produce a vector with the following repeating pattern:

```
1 1 2 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 ...
```

that ranges from one to some arbitrary stopping point.

I can hack it together using an `sapply` followed by an `unlist`, as in the following, but it sure feels like there should be a base call that is more direct than this.

```
repeating_function <- function(stop_point) { 
    res_list <- sapply(1:stop_point, FUN=function(x) {1:x}, simplify=TRUE)
    res      <- unlist(res_list)

    return(res)
}
```

Which produces:

```
repeating_function(5)

[1] 1 1 2 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: Your solution feels like the correct base R way to do it to me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier option would be

```
sequence(sequence(5))
#[1] 1 1 2 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 5
```

Wrapping in a function

```
repeating_function(val) {
   sequence(sequence(val))
  }
```

Comment: There it is, thanks @akrun! I don't see the value in naming a new function to accomplish this. As well, now that you've spotted `sequence`, that could just wrap another simply called sequence: `sequence(1:5)` produces the same result.